# design a hardware whether to base on arduino or raspberrypi

Tags: arduino

I want to build a device which can link some sensors and actuators, on the prototyping stage, I can use either arduino or raspberrypi to implement the functionality, now my puzzle is whether to use arduino or raspberrypi or both, because I want to build in a server in the device which could be restful, so arduino is not so preferable to build a a probable server, so raspberrypi seem to be perferable, but designing the open source hardware is more preferable with arduino. Anyway, my requirements on the software stack and server part is very high, arduino family like uno is not good enough to cope with.

I have seen many open source hardware or product built with arduino, but have no idea any products derived from raspberrypi. so if I prototype the hardware with PI, would it be easy to design the real product with core PI components, how much cost will be compared to that of using arduino?

Comment: there are arduino shaped boards that will run linux, the wikipedia arduino page liists some of them

Answer (score 2):

The [Pi Compute Module](http://www.raspberrypi.org/raspberry-pi-compute-module-new-product/) is designed explicitly for this purpose: being incorporated into a larger system. It's the Broadcom chip + eMMC Flash on an SODIMM card.

Comment: I did think of mentioning the compute module.  But I think unless you order 100s it's more expensive than a model B.  In addition you then have to put all the components back on (like USB and Ethernet) you lost from the Pi but do need.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are talking about hundreds of thousands of units you will have to use the whole Pi or nothing.

The core component is the [Broadcom 2835](http://www.broadcom.com/products/BCM2835) SOC (System On a Chip).  You can't buy them off eBay for a couple of pounds like an Atmel Atmega328.